# How to find the cause for the error: Provider error '8000ffff' Catastrophic failure DB2 V10

Tags: odbc, iis-6, db2, oledb, adodb

Somebody can help me to find the cause for the error: Provider error '8000ffff' Catastrophic failure In DB2 Server version 10.1.0.2?

The ASP code showed below works fine with DB2 Connect version 9.7.2:

```
ConnectStr = "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};Database=DBXX;Uid=myuser;Pwd=pypass;Hostname=localhost;Port=50000;Protocol=TCPIP;"
set con0 = CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
Con0.Open ConnectStr
set rs = CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" )
rs.ActiveConnection = Con0
rs.Open "select * from sysibm.sysdummy1", Con0
response.write(now & " --->>>" & rs(0))
con0.close()
set rs = nothing
set con0 = nothing
```

After installing the new driver of DB2Connect 10.1.0.2 Server this error starts to happen.

Our environment is:

- Windows Server 2003 R2 32 bits running in vmware

- MDAC 2.8 SP2

- OLEDB32.DLL 2.82.3959.0


Any suggestion is apreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, but you could try searching on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing some information from the connection string, everything started to work perfectly, to my surprise.
The connection string looks like this:

`ConnectStr = "Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};Database=DBXX;Uid=myuser;Pwd=pypass;"`